# Which unix compatibility toolchain to use with cabal install on windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc, haskell-platform, cabal-install

trying to install `BlogLiterately` on win7/64.

- installed HP 2014.2/64
- `cabal update`
- `cabal install cabal-install`
- renamed `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin\cabal.exe`
  to *.old
- `cabal update`
- `cabal install BlogLiterately` fails cuz needs unix toolchain to install new version of `network`
- tried installing `mingw`, but gave up cuz the package manager that pops up only lists packages with suffix `32`, i want `64`, can't tell from http://www.mingw.org/ if it supports 64 bit.
- tried installing `cygwin64`, added `C:\cygwin64\bin` to the *end* of `PATH`, didn't work, see on internet that people think `cygwin` doesn't work for ghc so well anymore, even though the original error said `cygwin` would work
- found http://msys2.github.io/, installed it, followed instructions to update with `pacman` on that page, used `Win64 Shell`
- got error that `HsOpenSSL` is missing c libs `eay32 ssl32`, googling says to install http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html then `cabal install HsOpenSSL --extra-include-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win64/include" --extra-lib-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win64"` -- this works, but can't find any official looking docs saying i need `Win32OpenSSL` -- why can't cabal install this for me?
- now `cabal install BlogLiterately` fails cuz `ghc.exe: unable to load package 'hs-bibutils-5.5'`

the error:

```
ghc.exe: warning: _stricmp from msvcrt is linked instead of __imp__stricmp
ghc.exe: warning: _stricmp from msvcrt is linked instead of __imp__stricmp
ghc.exe: warning: _atoi64 from msvcrt is linked instead of __imp__atoi64
ghc.exe: warning: toupper from msvcrt is linked instead of __imp_toupper
ghc.exe: warning: _strnicmp from msvcrt is linked instead of __imp__strnicmp
ghc.exe: C:\Users\nlab\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\hs-bibutils-5.5\HShs-bibutils-5.5.o: unknown symbol `strdup'
```

`cabal install hs-bibutils --reinstall --force-reinstalls` succeeds, but i get the same error when retrying the `BlogLiterately` install.  i tried moving `/c/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin` to the front of the `PATH` and again reinstalling `hs-bibutils`, same result.

what is the right way to do this?!?!  which unix toolchain are we supposed to use, and how are we supposed to configure it?  why isn't it enough that HP includes `mingw`'s binaries?  gah.

Comment: So far [minghc](https://github.com/fpco/minghc) worked for me without issues.

Comment: so is HP no longer the way to go on windows?  all the HP libraries are easily cabal installed on minghc?

Comment: The `network` library is primary designed for \*nix and is known to have problems in Windows environment, one of the main reasons of Haskell Platform for Windows (as I heard). Neil Mitchell, Michael Snoyberg and contributors were "tired" of the Haskell Platform cycle and went for the [minghc](https://github.com/fpco/minghc), which has as one of the advantages to deal with `network`. Hence, it is highly recommend to try `minghc`, although it isn't the *official* way (yet).

Comment: well after dealing with https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2502 / https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2525, minghc gave the exact same error for `hs-bibutils` :(  can any of you guys install hs-bibutils on 64 bit windows?

Comment: seems to be this? https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9215

Comment: well 32 bit worked, after failing to be able to install the latest HaXml, i randomly figured out i could install HaXml-1.23.3.  gah

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, new versions of the Haskell Platform for windows (since 8.0.1) allow network to build properly if the cabal file is augmented with a few extra settings as described on the platform website:  https://www.haskell.org/platform/

```
Modify your cabal config file (you can verify the location by running "cabal user-config init") to contain the following lines:
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\msys\usr\bin
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\mingw\lib
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.
```

Comment: The code block is incomplete